# How to hide specific pages or sections in LaTeX but keep it's side effect (like counter)?

Tags: xetex

I have a tex file that contains multiple sections. All sections start with a new page, and I want to build a separate file for each section. I can do this by using `\jobname` , but how can I remove unused sections from the output but keep side effects the section counter for the actually needed sections?
I want the exact result just like manually splitting the result pdf file by section.

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stackexchange! You can use `\include` to input the files, do first all LaTeX runs with all files and then use `\includeonly` for a last LaTeX run with only those files, you want to show in the result PDF.

Comment: But, in my latex file, each section have a section number, and if I `includeonly` the second subfile, will it show section 2 instead of section 1?

Comment: Sure, this is one of the *side effects* for *section counter* and *the exact result just like manually splitting the the result pdf file by section* you've IMHO asked for. If not, I do not understand your question.

Comment: But maybe you alternatively searching for a package like [`subfile`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfile).

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `\include` to include subfiles and `\includeonly` to control which subfile should show in output.

Another solution is to add a bookmark to each split point and use the following code to split it:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
filename = "main.pdf"

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    r = PdfReader(f)

    bookmarks = list(map(lambda x: (x.title, r.get_destination_page_number(x)), r.outline))
    print(bookmarks)
    for i, b in enumerate(bookmarks):
        begin = b[1]
        end  = bookmarks[i+1][1] if i < len(bookmarks) - 1 else len(r.pages)
        # print(len(r.pages[begin:end]))
        name = b[0] + ".pdf"
        print(f"{name=}: {begin=}, {end=}")
        with open(name, "wb") as f:
            w = PdfWriter(f)
            for p in r.pages[begin:end]:
                w.add_page(p)
            w.write(f)
```